# I am trying to insert a function in my VBA code to only fill a cell when another cell has data in it

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, date-time, auto-form-fill

This is my code. It fills the Date when I have this 
`=Updating_Date(B5)` typed in C5. What it is supposed to do is fill the Date ONLY when data is present in B5, and remove the Date when No data is present. Currently it displays Date no matter what. I need to write in a condition to make it ONLY display Date when data is present in Column B.

Below is what I have typed into a module, thanks to another user, with `=Updating_Date(B5)` entered in C5.

`Function Updating_Date(dependent_cell as Range) As Date
  Updating_Date = Date
End Function`

Again, this displays the Date no matter if data is in column B or not.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried googling for "vba condition"? Because this site is not a free macro writing service.

Comment: If my question was inappropriate I apologize and will delete it. I was looking for assistance or suggestions to what I currently had. I didn't realize asking for help writing that condition was breaking any rules..

Comment: This site is fully about helping you write that condition, but you should try to get a bit further maybe. If you try and run into an issue, this is the place to go and ask for help. But it is up to you to do the trying. ;-) However you already got an answer, but i think your question does not show enough effort. No worries though, no offense meant! You would have learnt and benefited more trying a bit harder i believe (and you already had the search word you needed: "condition").

Comment: I appreciate the advice!!  I'm honestly in a bit of crunch to get this working otherwise I probably would had even a little more. Generally I would have more time to experiment and get a better grasp as I would prefer to learn rather than ask for handouts.. When your not used to formulas or coding it's really tricky trying to jump into it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not understand your example clearly, but it looks like you could just use one of these cell formulas:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B5),"",TODAY())
=IF(ISBLANK(B5),"",NOW())
=IF(ISBLANK(B5),"",Updating_Date(B5))
```

If you want to do the check in VBA, here's an option:

```
Function Updating_Date(dependent_cell As Range)
    If LenB(dependent_cell.Value) > 0 Then Updating_Date = Date Else Updating_Date = ""
End Function
```

Not that the function can not return a date or else it'll return `0` instead of blank. I dropped that and added an `If` condition that returns blank if the `dependent_cell` is blank.

Comment: This seemed to work perfectly, just altering the formula to `=IF(ISBLANK(B5),"",Updating_Date(B5))`.   Thank you very much. I am 100% new to using formulas and especially vba.. Thanks again..